# Two seperate XMLHttpRequest are being made and I need to clear 'php://input' between them

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

So I am making two XMLHttpRequests in javascript like so

First request:

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //first .php page with access to the first table
  request.open('POST', 'http://website/table1.php', true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
// first array
  var slobString = JSON.stringify(bInfo);
  request.send(slobString);
```

Second Request:

```
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      //second .php page with access to the second table
      request.open('POST', 'http://website/table2.php', true);
      request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
      // second array 
      var slobString = JSON.stringify(slob);
      request.send(slobString);
```

I retrieve this information in php with

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

The logic is the same on each php page but assigned to different tables

```
    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO selectedSearch(name, website, i0, i1, i2, i3) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

//arrays start at 0
$i = 0;
//As long as variable i is less than the total length of the array we will continue to run this loop
while ($i < $arrayLength) {
  if($postResults != undefined) {
    //create variables equal to the contents inside the array(postResults)
    $var0 = $postResults[$i][0];
    $var1 = $postResults[$i][1];
    $var2 = $postResults[$i][2];
    $var3 = $postResults[$i][3];
    $var4 = $postResults[$i][4];
    $var5 = $postResults[$i][5];

    //bind them to the prepared statement to be placed inside the database companies
    $sql->bind_param('ssisss', $var0, $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5);
    //executes the sql statement
    $sql->execute();
  }
  $i++;
};
```

Just to better help you understand what information I am sending. This is not exactly what I am doing but more of a ELI5. I am building a program to search for people in a list and put that information into a two dimensional array that looks like `var slob = [['name', 'date', 'other'], ['name', 'date', 'other']]`

As soon as the program is done crawling the list it sends that array to a .php file to be stored inside table1 of my database. And then it displays the information on screen for a user to see. After that the user can review the information. If a user selects people from the original array then I store their selections into a new array and send that over to a different page to get put inside table2 of my database.

But because I am crawling the list inside javascript, a XMLHTTPRequest is the only way that I know how to send it over to php and php://input is the only way that I know how to retrieve it. But when I access 'php://input' it has both arrays and stores a lot of unwanted information inside table2.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem. I don't understand the two calls stuff and the need to clear 'php://input'. Each call to the script will have a specific context, so php://input is different on each call. Please be more specific about what you intend to do and what behavior you expect

Comment: @Pierre Right as I finished editing my post with more information you posted this comment. Refresh the page and it'll have my edit. Please let me know if I need to clarify further.

Comment: _"But when I access 'php://input' it has both arrays"_ - that's because you are sending both, in one request. _"and stores a lot of unwanted information inside table2"_ - well then we'd obviously have to see your PHP code that handles the data.

Comment: @Pierre Let me edit the question again with more info to clear this up.

Comment: @Pierre Take a look now.

Comment: If the script is inserting more data than you want, then most likely you are _sending_ more data than you think. So go properly check that - var_dump the content of php://input and after that exit, in both PHP scripts, and then check in the browser console, network panel, both what data you actually send and what the PHP scripts actually received.